# Why does this RegEx not match numbers, only characters?

Tags: regex

I'm building a RegEx-based Markdown parser. Whilst working on the RegEx to find reference-style link labels I've come across a bug in my RegEx that I can't see the problem with.

Given the following Markdown:

```
[me]: http://example.com
[her]: http://somewhere.com
[1]: http://nhs.net
[2]: http://test.com
[google it]: http://google.com
```

And this RegEX:

```
\[(\w+\s?+\w+)\]
```

I seem to only be able to detect [me], [her] and [google it] but not the labels [1] and [2]. I thought `\w` should detect both alphabetic and numeric characters?

**Edit:** Using PCRE RegEx parser

Comment: It would be great if you could share the regex flavor you are using: ICU, PCRE or JS? Any other?

Comment: Updated to state PCRE

Comment: Good, then in my alternative suggestion, you may omit the ``\`` before `]`: `[^][]` matches any char other than `[` and `]` in PCRE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\w+\s?+\w+` pattern matches at least 2 word chars because of the two `\w+` subpatterns.

If you want to match optional whitespace-separated word(s), use

```
\[(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\]
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TU4GFG/1)

**Details**:

- `\[` - an opening `[`
- `(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)` -  Group 1:

  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars
  - `(?:\s+\w+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

    - `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces (if you use `?`, 1 or 0 occurrences will get matched)
    - `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `]` - a closing `]` (does not need escaping)

An alternative regex - if you need to make sure the `[` and `]` are followed/preceded with a word char, use

```
\[\b([^\][]+)\b]
```

Where `\[\b` matches a `[` before a word char, `([^\][]+)` captures 1+ chars other than `[` and `]` and `\b]` matches a `]` after a word char.
See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TU4GFG/2)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you ever so much for the pattern and more so for the explanation. RegEx is so powerful but the patterns are nuts to understand!

Answer (score 0):

Your regex does not match those two numbers, because you expect 1+ characters with `\w+` and another 1+ characters with the second `\w+`. So at least 2 characters

In addition your `\s?+` is just weird. That means you want a optional whitespace but that once or more.

Comment: Your description of `\s?+` is weird, it either is a possessive optional whitespace or a syntax error.